# How to print the date and time in Python from string?

Tags: python

Should be quick, but I can't for the life of me figure this one out.

I'm given the following strings:

- 201408110000
- 201408120001
- 201408130002

Which I loaded as a date(?) time object via the following:

```
dt = time.strptime(datestring, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
```

Where datestring is the string.

From there, how do I output the following:

- 11-Aug-14
- 12-Aug-14
- 13-Aug-14

I tried `str(dt)` but all it gave me was this weird thing:

> time.struct_time(tm_year=2014, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=11, tm_hour=12,
>   tm_min=1, tm_sec=5, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=223, tm_isdst=-1)

What am I doing wrong? Anything I add so far to `dt` gives me `attribute does not exist` or something.

Comment: Have you tried `strftime`?

Comment: Yes, but I'm probably not doing it right. I keep getting `attribute does not exist`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **strftime**

```
>> dt = time.strftime('%d-%b-%Y', dt)
>> print dt
11-Aug-2014
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `time` module it return a time struct type. Using `datetime` returns a datetime type.

```
from datetime import datetime

datestring = '201408110000'

dt = datetime.strptime(datestring, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

print dt
2014-08-11 00:00:00

print dt.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
11-Aug-2014

print dt.strftime("%d-%b-%y")
11-Aug-14
```

Comment: Is datetime built-in to Python? I just used `import time`. I recall having to install a plug-in or something on my local computer (can't remember if it's datetime or dateutil or something else), which is something I can't do once I migrate this to a server.

Comment: `datetime` is standard. See list of formatting otions for `strftime` [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Comment: `datetime` is builtin. You should have installed [dateutil](https://labix.org/python-dateutil)

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
datestring = "201408110000"
print datetime.strptime(datestring, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S').strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
11-Aug-2014
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a lot of parsing of variety of input time formats, consider also installing and using the `dateutil` package.  The `parser` module will eat a variety of time formats without specification, such as this concise "one-liner":

```
from dateutil import parser
datestring = '201408110000'
print parser.parse(datestring).strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
```

This uses `parser` to eat the datestring into a `datetime`, which is then reformatted using `datetime.strftime()`, not to be confused with `time.strftime()`, used in a different answer.

See more at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil or the [python-dateutil](/questions/tagged/python-dateutil) tag.